# How to properly copy (scp/rsync) folder recursively?

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, scp

I would like to copy a folder hierarchy composed of 20k text files of about 10..500kB each.

I initially tried:

```
scp -r server:${REMOTE} ${LOCAL}
```

But it was too slow, so I tried with `rsync` instead:

```
scp -zr server:${REMOTE} ${LOCAL}
```

Again it was too slow, it took about 2 hours to complete.

I came across a third solution which was:

```
ssh server tar czf ~/tmp.tar.gz --directory=$(dirname $REMOTE) ${REMOTE}
scp server:tmp.tar.gz .
tar xzf --directory=${LOCAL} tmp.tar.gz
```

It is much faster but less convenient to use and I have to make sure `tmp.tar.gz` does not already exist.

Is there any intermediate alternative?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189878/parallelise-rsync-using-gnu-parallel

Comment: Parallel rsync over ssh doesn't look a good idea

Comment: `tar czf - /home/localuser/filefolder | ssh remote-machine@ip.address.of.remote.machine tar -xvzf -C /home/remoteuser/`

Comment: Well... I would like to copy from REMOTE to LOCAL.

Comment: have you tried just remotely mounting the destination?